# python syntax error while statement

Tags: python, syntax-error

I can't figure out were I'm going wrong and help would be much appreciated

```
the_number =random.randit(1, 9)
guess = int(input("take a guess: "))
while guess != the_number:
```

Why does it say there is a syntax error on the last line. (This is not the complete code)

Here's the whole code if it helps

```
import random 
print("guess a number between 1 and 9")
guess =input() 
guess =int(guess) 
the_number = (random.randint(1, 9)

while guess != the_number:  
 if guess  != the_number: 
  print("incorrect number guess again")
  continue 
 else: 
   print("congratulations you have guessed the number was, " , the_number)
   break
```

Comment: what's the next line? Right now, your syntax error is "uh, there's nothing after a while statement"

Comment: The error is probably due to the random `(` you have on the 5th line before `random.randint(1,9)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a colon in the code that gave you an error? The only way I can make a syntax error on that line is to remove the colon, or to replace the colon with a semicolon, like this:

```
>>> while guess != the_number
```

or this:

```
>>> while guess != the_number;
```

which *do* give the error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
  while guess != the_number
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This exact error happens to be the example error for the definition of 'Syntax Error' in the Python documentation
([Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#syntax-errors) or [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#syntax-errors) docs).

P.S. welcome to Stackoverflow! Next time you should post the error message you get too. And if you *are* a beginner, which is just fine, googling for your error message usually works great.

Comment: while guess != the_number:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
1|u0_a244@D2303:/ $

Comment: The caret is directly below while in the error message which is what confused me to start with

Comment: Oh, haha @OliverBond you don't have a closing parenthesis on the line above the while -- `the_number = (random.randint(1, 9)`   that's why it's good to post your code...

Comment: @slushy your comment would make a fine answer